# Why Spring BindingResult or validator do not show any errors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am trying to validate the Spring Bean containing email but neither the validator nor the BindingResult do not show any error when email in the request Bean comes as empty string.
Please, see the following code:

Bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.Email;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.NotEmpty;

@Component("grouponRedemptionFormBean")
@Scope("prototype")
public class GrouponRedemptionBean {

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email addresss.")
@Email(message = "Please correct your email.")
private String  email;
   …
}
```

Controller:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class GrouponVoucherRedemptionController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultBeanValidator")
private Validator validator;

@RequestMapping(value="/groupon-redemption.ep", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String PostGrouponRedemption(@Valid @ModelAttribute GrouponRedemptionBean grouponRedemptionBean, BindingResult bindingResult,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model){

    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(grouponRedemptionBean, "grouponRedemptionFormBean");
    validator.validate(grouponRedemptionBean, errors);
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        bindingResult.addAllErrors(errors);
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return GROUPON_REDEMPTION_VIEW;
    }    
...
```

XML configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 7):

You have wrong argument order - `BindingResult` must be immediately after the model object (`GrouponRedemptionBean` in your case). See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments):

> The `Errors` or `BindingResult` parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have more than one model object and Spring will create a separate `BindingResult` instance for each of them so the following sample won't work:
>
> **Invalid ordering of BindingResult and @ModelAttribute.**
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, Model model, BindingResult result) { ... }
> ```
>
> Note, that there is a `Model` parameter in between `Pet` and `BindingResult`. To get this working you have to reorder the parameters as follows:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult result, Model model) { ... }
> ```

Comment: I changed the location of BindingResult and added Validator - the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or this

```
<bean id="validator"
  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```